# How to fix the error of ConnectionRefusedError after creating an executable file

Tags: python, mysql-connector, cx-freeze

I created an executable file from a Python system using MySQL Connector. I use the cx_freeze to get it. This my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
executables = [Executable("general.py", base=base)]#, icon='accept.ico')]
#Renseignez ici la liste complète des packages utilisés par votre application
packages = ["idna", "__future__", "PyQt5","sys", "numpy", "cv2", "pyzbar", "validate_email", "urllib.request", "mysql.connector", "datetime", "face_recognition"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages':packages,
        'include_files':['icones','TEACH_images']


    },
}

setup(
    name = "bis",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'Voici mon programme',
    executables = executables
)
```

Every thing is working on my PC, but always when I try to test it on any other PC, I get this error:

[image: Error]

How to fix this error?

Comment: Do those other PCs have MySQL running on localhost, port 3306?

Comment: Of course not, what I want to do is to create an application that can works on any other PC without installing python or mysql or anything else. So is that possible or should I install mysql when I use the application? I didn't find a precise answer

Comment: As the error _"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' [..]"_ indicates, the program is trying to connect to localhost port 3306, so if you want to connect to a common database server, you must configure your application to use the correct host name and port.

Comment: I understand you but can you help to configure my application to use the correct host name and port

Comment: You haven't shown how you create connections, so we can't really help you.

Comment: I used mysql workbench to create my database and then I called it in my application like this:

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", password="ba9lewa94", host="localhost", database="bis_nxg")
my_cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered= True)

Comment: Then you need to change that `host="localhost"` to the hostname of the machine hosting your MySQL server. Localhost is a hostname which means "this machine", you need to use a hostname (or IP address) that is accessible by the other hosts. You also need to configure MySQL to listen on that host/IP address.